# Больше чем одно предложение во вставке из тире

Tags: пунктуация

Совы, можно ли во вставке, сделанной посредством тире, писать больше чем одно предложение? Или это можно только в скобкообразной вставке делать?

`Я вечером пошёл – может быть, однако, не вечером. Я этого не помню – в ресторан и там увидел мини-кактус.`

`Я завтра, например, – могу, кстати, и не завтра. Когда вы сами хотите? – могу к вам прийти-таки.`

Comment: Я сам не знаю ответ на этот вопрос, но, делая правки и оставляя активность, пытаюсь продвинуть его на первое место, чтобы и я узнал) Голос тоже поставил.

Comment: Леопольд, тоже так делайте, нсли вам точно нужен ответ)

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Леопольд, делай регулярно правки в своем вопросе, и тогда оно будет на первом месте в "текущих" и его начнут замечать. Можно делать правку, потом убирать ее, и так, пока не ответят))